using rsync to merge backup folders
I routinely make backup copies of my user folder from multiple computer systems. I was unable to find an example on how to merge all my backup folders into one inclusive one. If anyone knows how to write a script to merge multiple older backup folders into one inclusive one containing the most recent files, I would be greatful.
I tried to use rsync to merger two user folder backups into one inclusive folder with all the latest directories and files. First I created two directories on my external backup drive where the backups are located; /merge and /tomerge. The folder I wanted to merge the other folders into was placed in the /merge directory. The folder I wanted to merge into it was placed in the /tomerge directory. Both user folders have the same name and mostly the same directory structure. If the file exists it should be skipped unless it is more recent. I also wanted the remove the source files to free up disk space after the merge. I used the following command:
rsync -rauv --progress --remove-source-files tomerge/ merge/
It seems to have transferred 244 files, but the number of files and size of the merge folder did not increase.
I got a couple of errors (code 22 and 23). Below is the last part of the progress list, but it appears nothing was transferred.
vance/Documents/Manufactures Data/aavid/._62725_9.75X6X2.28_0.51-degC-per-Watt.PDF
          4,096 100%    6.94kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#239, ir-chk=1014/62203)
vance/Documents/Manufactures Data/aavid/.directory
             61 100%    0.10kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#240, ir-chk=1013/62203)
vance/Documents/Manufactures Data/aavid/62725_9.75X6X2.28_0.51-degC-per-Watt.PDF
         84,241 100%  134.42kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#241, ir-chk=1012/62203)
vance/Documents/Online Orders/1Prov_number.txt
             73 100%    0.08kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#242, ir-chk=1161/63023)
vance/Documents/Online Orders/1V_number~
             54 100%    0.06kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#243, ir-chk=1160/63023)
vance/Downloads/EPSON_DS-510/Image Scan vs Manual
        413,103 100%  120.91MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#244, ir-chk=1001/70705)
rsync: [generator] recv_generator: mkdir "/media/vance/UBUNTU/merge/vance/KiCad/Projects/1000W PFC " failed: Invalid argument (22)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
vance/KiCad/Projects/1000W PFC /

sent 22,157,872 bytes  received 2,921,466 bytes  477,701.68 bytes/sec
total size is 95,518,308,087  speedup is 3,808.65
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1338) [sender=3.2.7]

Where did I go wrong?
